# Не загружает fxml файл

Tags: java, linux, javafx, fxml

Написал мини проект на java протестировал в intellijIDEA. Всё работает. Создал jar запустил в Windows, все работает.
Теперь захотелось мне запустить с Linux(Kali если имеет значение) он мне выдал приличное сообщение об ошибке:

```
    Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:473)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:372)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:941)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:973)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:198)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/javafx/css/StyleConverterImpl
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1009)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:801)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:699)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:622)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:580)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton$StyleableProperties.<clinit>(JFXButton.java:196)
    at com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton.<init>(JFXButton.java:156)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:560)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1019)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:754)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3253)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3210)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3179)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3152)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3129)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3122)
    at sample.main.Main.start(Main.java:23)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:919)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(PlatformImpl.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(PlatformImpl.java:418)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:417)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.javafx.css.StyleConverterImpl
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    ... 37 more
Exception running application sample.main.Main
```

Как я понял ошибка происходит при попытке загрузить fxml в Main Классе, вот код метода :

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample/fxml/main.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Crypter");
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 643, 431);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/sample/fxml/images/icon4.png")));
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/sample/fxml/styles/configStyle.css").toExternalForm());
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    primaryStage.show();
```

Всё же хотелось бы узнать в чем мой косяк, 
Заранее спасибо за любую помощь :)

Comment: вы собирали джарник под 8 джавой, а запускаете на 9 ?

Comment: на 10*, а разве там путь меняется?

Answer (score 0):

У вас на пути классов не хватает класса `com.sun.javafx.css.StyleConverterImpl`. Вам надо найти этот класс в библиотеках и добавить соответствующую библиотеку.

Comment: Не подскажете, как в intellij idea найти класс по названию или вы имеете ввиду, что его нет вообще в java. Я прост ставил полную java 10 с оф. сайта, не знаю почему не робит

Comment: Если класса нет, то вы не можете его найти в intellij idea.

Answer (score -1):

Максимально глупая ошибка. 
Юзал библиотеку jfoenix 8.0, когда использую java 9.
Сейчас скачал jfoenix 9.0 всё заработало